# Finding the distance between two lexicographically ordered integer sequences.

Tags: sequences-and-series

For example if I have the sequence 000, 001, 010, 011, 100, 101, 110, 111, then the distance between 000, and 010 should be 2, the distance between 000 and 011 should be 3, etc. I can assume the sequences will be generated by taking the Cartesian product $A \times A$ where $A = \{0, 1, ..., n\}$.

Answer (score 0):

I realized this is just a sequence of base-$n$ numbers, so the easiest approach I've found is to convert the two numbers to base-10 and take the absolute value of their difference (using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28666223/9967871) method in particular, in case anyone is interested).